# Comparative form of adverbs

Tags: adverbs, degree-of-comparison

What is the comparative form of the adverb *always*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Are you asking if there is a comparative of an absolute value? It is not quite like _often_, or _frequently._

Comment: @Cascabel Exactly my thought. How could you "more always" eat beef on Sundays?

Comment: "more always", assuming the question is about grammaticality, not truth.

Comment: [*Larger businesses are more likely always to use application forms*...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22more+likely+always%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY4ankpuDYAhXKMywKHRKICVk4ChD8BQgQKAE&biw=1257&bih=660) Again, not the comparative form of "always", but it's pretty close...

Comment: No research, no effort, and exactly how useful is this question to future visitors? Yet this question remains open...sigh... C'mon @The darkness tell us "why" you think there is the comparative form of "always"? Did you try looking it up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

There no more exists — **in *practice* rather than in *theory*** — a usable comparative degree of *always* than there exists one of *never*: these are not words that readily and meaningfully admit comparative or superlative degrees.

Something either *is* or is *not* always, because once something is “always” you cannot make it “more always” or “less always”. It’s like how when you have two events that both never happen, you cannot say that one of them happens “more never” or “less never” than another does.

Ignore the commenters. There are [no citations of such a thing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+always%2C+alwayser&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20always%3B%2Cc0) that are not false positives. You would be perceived as ungrammatical and confusing.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A 'Nearly always' is not a comparative form. 'Always, more always' would show absolute and comparative forms, and the latter is nonsense and unacceptable. Occasionally, one meets idiomatic usages that buck the trend, like 'more full' as shorthand for 'more nearly full'.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That is true, however the OP is asking specifically for a _comparative_. I might also add _almost_ always.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You're saying that 'That's nearly always true' is justifiable here? Helpful?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think Mari-Lou is simply commenting on the answerer's point that "always...does not admit modifiers of degree". "Nearly always" may not be a comparative, but "nearly" certainly modifies the degree of "always". Equally "almost never", does much the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I think we all accept that "always" and "never" cannot possibly have comparatives and superlatives. But they can have "modifiers of degree", is the point I take @Mari-Lou to be making.

Comment: @WS2 Perhaps the question deserves a longer life through editing to reflect the "degrees of modification" I am withdrawing my vote to close, with the hope that the question might be whipped into shape to adhere to our site standards.

Comment: It's easy to construct examples where "more always" is used with jocular intent.  Just because they're not true, it doesn't mean they're not English.

Comment: So you would rather lie?  Why is it sophistry to give a truthful answer?

Answer (score 0):

'Always' and 'never' are limit quantifiers of time, just as 'all' and 'none' are limit quantifiers (non-count) of other things.  As limits, they can only take degree modifiers (adverbs) that remain within the limits.  We form comparisons with 'more' or 'less', but only 'more' corresponds to the grammatical *comparative*.  Since 'always' is an upper limit, we cannot compare it upwards.  Only if we consider the limits as fuzzy can we apply modifiers that probe that fuzzy area.